# How to make function sleep in QML

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I have got a function and the `Timer` in QML. How can I make it sleep for a while and invoke the function after?

My timer looks like:

```
Timer {
    id: timer
    interval: 5000
    repeat: false
    onTriggered: procPage()
}
```

The problem is that when I start the `Timer`, function `procPage()` invokes immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer to my question, thanks to *BaCaRoZzo*.

So, the `Timer` in QML can work in both ways. If we set [`triggeredOnStart`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-timer.html#triggeredOnStart-prop) equal to `true` `Timer` will immediately invoke `procPage()` and if we set `triggeredOnStart` to `false` the `Timer` will wait for `interval` to pass and then invoke the function `procPage()`.